# Could you let me know what went wrong in this function? (Beginner)

Tags: function, return, project

CODE: function power(x, n){

```
return x**n
```

}

power(2,5)

QUESTION:
why am I unable to see the answer 120 be logged, without putting console log into the function? help me understand the return statement.

Comment: What programming language is this?  How are you running it?

Comment: What has this go to do with the `[project]` tag?  How is that relevant to the question you asked?

Comment: *"help me understand the return statement"* - In most programming languages, it returns a value to the caller.  It doesn't **log** or **output** the value.  If that is going to happen, it will happen in the code that calls the function (or method or procedure or subroutine or ... whatever it is called in the PL you are using).